# Pandas - fill value in new column based on which column is not empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

|  | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 0.325 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  | 0.23378 |  |
| 3 |  | 2.3242 |  |  |
| 4 | 0.42 |  |  |  |
| 5 | 6.293 |  |  |  |

The four columns represent different water depths and the values are temperature measurements.
There is only one non-NA value in the four columns a, b, c, d. I want to aggregate the values into one column `value` (or water temperature) and the 'position' of the value, i.e. the associated column name in a new `column` (or water depth) column.

Expected output format:

|  | value | column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.325 | b |
| 2 | 0.23378 | c |
| 3 | 2.3242 | b |
| 4 | 0.42 | a |
| 5 | 6.293 | a |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.stack().rename_axis(['value','column']).reset_index()
```

Comment: perfect. i knew it was easy, but it's hard to find if you don't know what it's called you're searching for :)